# $P(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2<1)$ under i.i.d. standard normal distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

a, b, c, d are i.i.d and follow $N(0,1)$, calculate $P(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2<1)$?

I wonder if there is a simple way?

Comment: Have a look at the Chi-Square distribution, $\large{\chi^2_k}$.

Comment: @callculus42, oh I see. It is indeed simple. Thank you!

Comment: It pleases me, that it´s all clear.